# Creating a List of Dynamic Textboxes and Return it to View via Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to loop through a specific textbox which was created dynamically using jquery. Now in the formcollection, I want to retrieve those values in a loop from the controller as list of sting and return that list back to the view.

```
foreach(string item in form.Keys){
   if (actCount > 1)
   {
       for (int i = 1; i < actCount; i++)
       {
           if (frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i].Substring(0, 3) != "165")
           {   
                ViewBag.SaveError = "";
                ViewBag.SaveError = "Invalid customer account number detected. Account number must start with 165 but not " + frm["txtAccountNumberField" + i].Substring(0, 3);

                ViewBag.ValidationStatus = false;

                Response.Write(frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i]);
                lst.Add(frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i]);

                ViewBag.ListOfAccounts = lst;
                this.redisplay();

                return View(customerModel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the view when I run the code as shown below

```
for (int i = 1; i < accountsTotal; i++)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfAccounts)
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

I would be grateful if a solution or suggestion is rendered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First make sure your ViewBag.ListOfAccounts has some value in it.. secondly don't try to access it via for loop and take all value in another variable and cast it to desired type.. var list = ViewBag.ListOfAccounts != null ? (List<string>)ViewBag.ListOfAccounts : new List<string>();

Comment: Thanks for the reply but from my guesses, the error itself is coming from the controller because I don't see the values of the controller in form adding up to the list I created in the controller. Please check the code foreach(){} section

Comment: can you paste the entire controller action method as well as the form HTML if this action is POST and expecting inputs from UI ?

Comment: Yes action method is POST and it is receiving the formcollection because when I use the following; foreache(string lst in form.Keys){Response.Write("Control Name:: " + item + "  and Control Value:: " + frm[item] + "<br/>")} it prints all the values and their keys and their values

Comment: try to check if it enters if (frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i].Substring(0, 3) != "165")           { ... condition

Comment: I have commented that line and tried to run the line lst.Add(frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i]); I realised that only the first item is added and the rest does not add to the list. How do I add these item to the list I created?

Comment: You have added return View() inside the loop. you should get it out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following.
You should get your return statement outside for loop

```
foreach(string item in form.Keys){
   if (actCount > 1)
   {
       for (int i = 1; i < actCount; i++)
       {
           if (frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i].Substring(0, 3) != "165")
           {   

                ViewBag.SaveError = "Invalid customer account number detected. Account number must start with 165 but not " + frm["txtAccountNumberField" + i].Substring(0, 3);

                ViewBag.ValidationStatus = false;


                lst.Add(frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i]);

                ViewBag.ListOfAccounts = lst;
                this.redisplay();


            }
        }
    }
}
return View(customerModel);
```

Also make sure following condition is working correctly as expected

```
if (frm["AccountNumberTextBox" + i].Substring(0, 3) != "165")
```

In your view instead of accessing items directly from the `ViewBag`, those in a variable

```
    @{
    @*I assume you want all items as string *@
    var list = ViewBag.ListOfAccounts != null ? (List<string>)ViewBag.ListOfAccounts : new List<string>();

}
```

And use this variable `list` to iterat through for loop

Comment: Thumbs up KD!!! I think on following your advise, I am getting headway gradually and I think I have been on the right path but the logic and where some calls are made is what I have to reconsider. Thanks for now but will be back if the need be. Thank you so much!!